# Data inserted using SqlBulkCopy takes 9x to 92x more space in the database than using INSERT statements

Tags: .net, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console application inserting data into a SQL Server 2017 (14.0.1000.169) table. It previously used simple `INSERT` statements. I changed it to use `SqlBulkCopy`, but found that it started using up space in the DB very quickly! Measuring the space used before and after data insertion using `EXEC sp_spaceused` shows that each inserted row takes on average:

- 28 bytes/row for `INSERT` (which sounds about right)
- 256 bytes/row for Bulk Copy with Default options
- 2585 bytes/row for Bulk Copy with TableLock option

The same data is being inserted in every case. This happens whether the recovery model is set to **Simple** or **Bulk-logged**.

The insert code is simple enough:

```
using (var transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
    DataTable dt = CreateDataTable();
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction) {DestinationTableName = $"[MyTable]"};
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

The table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] 
(
    A [datetime] NOT NULL,
    B [int] NOT NULL,
    C [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    D [varbinary](max) NULL,
    E [varchar](250) NULL,
    F [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

What's going on here and how do I get fast inserts without using up huge amounts of space?

**Edit:** I tried it with trace flag 692 on and it then uses 1767 bytes/row with TableLock, 45 bytes/row with Default options.

Comment: What's "SQL Server 14"? SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2017 (which is major version 14)? Explaining these results for 2017 would be easier than for 2014.

Comment: What are the autogrowth settings for this data file? Any indexes? Fill factor settings? You have a varchar(max) and varbinary(max) this is probably a big contributor.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's 2017 - edited to clarify.

Comment: Then you're likely running into [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/). From 2016 onwards, SQL Server grabs a lot more free space on minimally logged bulk inserts, to speed them up, but then things won't be filled up well unless you use properly sized batches. (An alternative is trace flag 692, which disables the new algorithm, but tuning the batch size is a better long term solution, or switching to regular inserts in a transaction if your batches are only ever very small.)

Comment: @JacobH Autogrowth is set to "By 64 MB, Unlimited" (the default, I believe). The only index is column A (datetime), non-clustered. Fill factor is set to 0.

I should perhaps add that there are many tables with the same schema (for partitioning). They all grow evenly (proportionally to the number of rows inserted).

Comment: Nice find @JeroenMostert

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think that's it - if I enable trace flag 692 and use Default options it uses 45 bytes/row. This is still not ideal, though, and I think my best solution is, sadly, to go back to INSERT statements. Great troubleshooting, anyway!

Comment: For what it's worth, bulk insert is both very fast and economical with space if you insert very large batches, which is what it's there for. With 30 bytes/row (which is very small and should only be possible if all your text fields are empty) you'd need on the order of 2200 rows per batch (or more) to make bulk inserting worthwhile. If your scenario is to speed up inserts for smaller batches, you might want to look at in-memory OLTP with natively compiled stored procedures, either as base tables or as intermediates in table-valued parameters.

Comment: @EM0, you could always bulk insert into a staging table, insert into the final table from the staging table, and delete the staging table.